# What's the point of the axiom of extensionality?

Tags: logic, set-theory

The axiom of extensionality is:

> ${\forall}a({\forall}b({\forall}c(((c{\in}a){\iff}(c{\in}b)){\iff}(a=b))))$

The definition of $(P{\iff}Q)$ is:

> ${\lnot}((P{\implies}Q){\implies}({\lnot}(Q{\implies}P)))$

or, in other words

> $(P{\land}Q){\lor}({\lnot}P{\land}{\lnot}Q)$

In the case of the statement $((c{\in}a){\iff}(c{\in}b))$, this leads us to two options: $((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b))$ and $({\lnot}(c{\in}a){\land}{\lnot}(c{\in}b))$. So far nothing weird.

Now, let's see all the possible results of the axiom.

> 1.$((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b)){\land}(a=b)$
>
> 2.${\lnot}((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b)){\land}{\lnot}(a=b)$
>
> 3.$({\lnot}(c{\in}a){\land}{\lnot}(c{\in}b)){\land}(a=b)$
>
> 4.${\lnot}({\lnot}(c{\in}a){\land}{\lnot}(c{\in}b)){\land}{\lnot}(a=b)$

Coincidentally, they are also all possible statements regarding the statements $((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b))$ and $(a=b)$: both parts are true, the first part is true and the other is false, the second part is true and the first is false and neither is true. The axiom seems not to state anything new, because rephrased it's just produces a list of all possible options regarding the two parts of the statement. Worse, it doesn't seem to say anything about equality, since it allows for $a=b$ with both $(c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b)$ and ${\lnot}((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b))$.

So, what is the point of this axiom? And in what way does it say anything about equality?

Comment: Equality of sets is not really defined without extensionality. The axiom says that sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. This very obvious fact is not true a priori.

Comment: The axiom as stated looks wrong. I believe it should read ${\forall}a({\forall}b(({\forall}c((c{\in}a){\iff}(c{\in}b))){\iff}(a=b)))$ (two sets are equal iff for all $c$ they agree on membership of $c$).

Comment: @arkeet What's the difference in results?

Comment: With the axiom as stated, you can prove something like "Suppose $1 \in a$ and $1 \in b$. Then $a = b$." This is clearly undesirable if we want to do math. It is also inconsistent, for if also $2 \in a$ and $2 \notin b$, we would also prove $a \ne b$.

Comment: Hint: your analysis of a propositional statement of the form $(P \iff Q) \iff R$ is incorrect. When you list "all the possible results of the axiom", you get $8$ cases not $4$.

Comment: What additional cases do I get?

Comment: Equally importantly, the correct form of the axiom is $[ (\forall x)[ x \in a \Leftrightarrow x \in b] ] \Leftrightarrow R$ where $R$ is $a = b$. So there is a quantifier that has to be dealt with, not just two biconditionals. The parentheses in the statement in the question seem to be incorrect. arkeet pointed this out above.

Comment: Wait, how would "Suppose $1{\in}a$ and $1{\in}b$. Then $a=b$" be proved in my version? It says that for all $c$, $a=b$ iff $c{\in}a{\iff}c{\in}b$. If I used $1$ as $c$ then the only result I'd get is that my statement is one of the 2 results (1. and 4.) mentioned above. I would then need to test for all possible $c$, not just $1$ to show which one of these results is the correct one. (I think I understand the axiom more now, but now I don't understand why my version is false).

Comment: The axiom as stated says "for all $a,b,c$, if $c \in a \Leftrightarrow c \in b$ then $a = b$". In that case, you can take $a = \{1,2\}$, $b = \{1,3\}$, $c = 1$ and your axiom would imply $a = b$. But the correct axiom would not, because we do not have $(\forall x)[x\in a \Leftrightarrow x \in b]$.

Comment: @Qwedfsf The difference here is the difference between $\forall a;\forall b;(P(a)\iff Q(a, b))$ and $\forall a;(P(a)\iff\forall b;Q(a,b))$. The way you wrote it, consider $a=\{1,2\}$, $b=\{1, 3\}$, and $c=1$. The axiom would say $(1\in\{1,2\}\land1\in\{1,3\})\iff\{1,2\}=\{1,3\}$, which you could use to prove $\{1,2\}=\{1,3\}$, which is just false. The real axiom would say $\forall c;(c\in\{1,2\}\land c\in\{1,3\})\iff\{1,2\}=\{1,3\}$, which is true. You can't simplify this logic to cases.

Answer (score 6):

You are misunderstanding the point of extensionality: its purpose is basically to help us prove that sets are equal. With Extensionality, if I can prove that A and B have the same elements, then I've proved that A=B. Without Extensionality, you could have two sets which are not equal but which have the same elements.

Put another way, Extensionality says that *a set is determined by its elements*. That may seem obvious; if so, great! The axiom is what codified this 'obvious' fact. (Also note that there are interesting set theories which reject Extensionality - it's not obviously true in all contexts!)

Comment: looks like you've missed your breakfast haha

Comment: @basket . . . what the actual [beep], autocorrect?! fixed.

Comment: "Without Existentiality, you could have two sets which are not equal but which have the same elements" In what way doesn't ths situation $((c{\in}a){\land}(c{\in}b)){\land}{\lnot}(a=b)$, which the axiom allows for, allow it?

Comment: It could be that $c \in a \cap b$, but $d \in a$ and there is a $d$ with $d \not \in b$, and so $a \not = b$.  The axiom says that $a = b$ is equivalent to $(\forall x)[x \in a \Leftrightarrow x \in b]$. Have you misread the quantifier, or misplaced some parentheses? @Qwedfsf

Comment: Consider $a = \{1,2\}$ and $b = \{1,3\}$. Then $1 \in a \cap b$, and $a \not = b$,  and we can let $d  = 2$ in my example.

Comment: @Qwedfsf You are misinterpreting the axiom: Extensionality says $\forall a,b[(\forall c(c\in a\iff c\in b))\iff a=b]$. That is, two sets are equal iff **all** their elements are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you read Frege's papers, you will find him to be critical of intensional logicians.  By contrast Frege's logic had as its ground of truth an extensional semantics.  This is why Frege so adamantly distinguished between a 
concept and the extension of a concept.  The original distinction between intension and extension is order-theoretic.  Aristotelian term logic semantics is extensional - arising with respect to a correspondence theory of truth based on individuals.  So, a "whole" class has as least as many individuals as its "parts" (fish are a part of the class of animals).  Leibniz inverted this sense of the part-whole relation to its converse ordering.  Hence Leibnizian logic is the intensional logic that Frege had been criticizing (although he had been motivated by Leibniz in other ways).

A problem that Frege ran into is that a function can be described in a multiplicity of ways.  The expression $x^2$ is not the expression $x*x$ even though they are "the same".  The modern notion of intension is characterized by this diversity of grammatical forms.  Extensionality is precisely how mathematicians may speak of different grammatical forms as being the same.

Now, as has been observed in the comments, you have not written the axiom of extensionality in the form of the received paradigm.  Because of Skolem's criticism of Zermelo in the first half of the twentieth century, set theory defers the account of identity to first-order predicate logic.  That is, set 
theory is "just another theory" according to this view.  And, predicate logic only needs to interpret the sign of equality with respect to substitutability.  It does not warrant the uses of identity.  The direction of your biconditional with the identity statement as the antecedent is an instantiation of Leibniz' indiscernibility of identicals.  This is considered part of first-order predicate logic.  The direction of your biconditional with the identity statement as the consequent is the warrant for using identity statements within the theory.  It is only that direction which is the axiom of extension under the received paradigm.

At the heart of this division is what is called the ontological view of identity.  It is often attributed to an author named Wittgenstein.  Since it is conceivable that two objects which are not the same will satisfy every available predicate, except for those involving names, one may not be able to depend upon warranting to determine an individual.  So warranted identity is not part of the standard account for first-order predicate logic.